# Ask for confirmation before deleting repeating tasks in org-agenda views

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

By customizing `org-agenda-confirm-kill`, I am able to get confirmation when I kill a task in an agenda view. I can set this to `t` to always ask for confirmation (which I don't want to do, because I usually just kill one off tasks instead of marking them `DONE`), or to a number `n` so that I have to confirm when a TODO spans `n` or more lines. I currently have this set as follows:

```
(setq org-agenda-confirm-kill 2)
```

This will prevent me from accidentally removing a TODO with notes or other information that I am not seeing when in agenda view. However, I am also worried about accidentally deleting repeating tasks. **Is there any way to get confirmation in the agenda views before killing repeating tasks?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advise `org-agenda-kill` to check `org-get-repeat` and prompt if there is a repeater.  Use a `:before-while` advice so that execution stops if the querying function returns false.  Since we're doing this from the agenda we will first have to find and go to the actual location to check the repeater.

```
(defun org-agenda-repeating-p ()
  (let ((pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker (thing-at-point 'line))))
    (save-window-excursion
      (org-goto-marker-or-bmk pos)
      (org-get-repeat))
    ))


(defun query-if-repeating (&rest args)
  (if (not (org-agenda-repeating-p))
      t
    (y-or-n-p "Entry repeats.  Kill?"))
  )

(advice-add 'org-agenda-kill :before-while 'query-if-repeating)
```

Comment: This works great for TODOs with a repeater, but for some reason prevents me from killing any tasks without a repeater.

Comment: @elethan `query-if-repeating` needs to return `t`  if the task isn't repeating, which it wasn't.  I edited in a fix.

Comment: One more little hiccup...Now if I press "n" when prompted, it will still kill the line...

Comment: Fixed again.  Try this version

Comment: That did it. Thanks for all the work!

Comment: I did applied this to `org-agenda-schedule` and I find it incredibly useful.